# Freezed Union Pattern matching in pure Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, pattern-matching

I dont like using code generator, but freezes [union/when](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed#when) generate code that are very useful.

Example:

```
@freezed
class Union with _$Union {
  const factory Union(int value) = Data;
  const factory Union.loading() = Loading;
  const factory Union.error([String? message]) = ErrorDetails;
}

var union = Union(42);
print(
  union.when(
    (int value) => 'Data $value',
    loading: () => 'loading',
    error: (String? message) => 'Error: $message',
  ),
);
```

Is there a way to reproduce freezed union pattern matching in pure dart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can, of course, it will just involve a lot of boilerplate. Here's a barebones example from your code, but of course it's missing most of the features of freezed sealed classes:

```
enum _UnionTag {
  data,
  loading,
  error,
}

class Union {
  final _UnionTag _tag;
  final int? _value;
  final String? _errorMessage;

  const Union(int value)
      : _tag = _UnionTag.data,
        _value = value,
        _errorMessage = null;

  const Union.loading()
      : _tag = _UnionTag.loading,
        _value = null,
        _errorMessage = null;

  const Union.error([String? errorMessage])
      : _tag = _UnionTag.error,
        _value = null,
        _errorMessage = errorMessage;

  T when<T>(
    T Function(int value) data, {
    required T Function() loading,
    required T Function(String? errorMessage) error,
  }) {
    switch (_tag) {
      case _UnionTag.data:
        return data(_value!);
      case _UnionTag.loading:
        return loading();
      case _UnionTag.error:
        return error(_errorMessage);
    }
  }
}
```